# how do i parse xml webpage in perl

Tags: xml, perl, xml-parsing

hello Currently i am able to parse the xml file if it is saved in my folder from the webpage.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use XML::Simple;

my $parser = new XML::Simple;
my $data = $parser->XMLin("config.xml");
print Dumper($data);
```

But it does not work if i am trying to parse it from the website.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use XML::Simple;

my $parser = new XML::Simple;
my $data = $parser->XMLin("http://website/computers/computers_main/config.xml");
print Dumper($data);
```

it gives me following error "File does not exist: http://website/computers/computers_main/config.xml at test.pl line 12"

How do I parse multiple xml files from the webpage? i have to grab multiple xml form the websites and parse it. can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Super Edit:** This method will require WWW::Mechanize but it will allow you to login to your website then get the xml page. You will have to change a few things which are found in the comments. Hope this helps.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use XML::Simple;
use WWW::Mechanize;

# Create a new instance of Mechanize
$bot = WWW::Mechanize->new();
# Create a cookie jar for the login credentials
$bot->cookie_jar(
        HTTP::Cookies->new(
            file           => "cookies.txt",
            autosave       => 1,
            ignore_discard => 1,
    )
);
# Connect to the login page
$response = $bot->get( 'http://www.thePageYouLoginTo.com' );
# Get the login form
$bot->form_number(1);
# Enter the login credentials.
# You're going to have to change the login and 
# pass(on the left) to match with the name of the form you're logging
# into(Found in the source of the website). Then you can put your 
# respective credentials on the right.
$bot->field( login => 'thisIsWhereYourLoginInfoGoes' );
$bot->field( pass => 'thisIsWhereYourPasswordInfoGoes' );
$response =$bot->click();
# Get the xml page
$response = $bot->get( 'http://website/computers/computers_main/config.xml' );
my $content = $response->decoded_content();
my $parser = new XML::Simple;
my $data = $parser->XMLin($content);
print Dumper($data);
```

Give this a go. Uses LWP::Simple as answered above. It just connects to the page and grabs the content of that page (xml file) and runs in through XMLin.
**Edit:** added simple error checking at the get $url line.
**Edit2:** Keeping the code here because it should work if a login is not required.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use XML::Simple;
use LWP::Simple;

my $parser = new XML::Simple;

my $url = 'http://website/computers/computers_main/config.xml';
my $content = get $url or die "Unable to get $url\n";
my $data = $parser->XMLin($content);

print Dumper($data);
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your reply.

I tried doing as above but for some reason i am getting error saying  "unable to get the url". Any idea what could go wrong with it. 
I have installed both modules properly.

Comment: I'm thinking it may be an error with the URL only because i'm using a url with the same format as above and it appears to be working for me. Have you tried a different url? You can google 'filetype:xml someQuery' to get some test xml files. Just grab their URL's and put them in the script above, this way we can see if its your URL or the script.

Comment: you are correct. it is authentication issue.
i have to manually log in to access that url. Is there a way around to pass the authentication in perl and parse the url that is needed?

Comment: Just added a new code block that you can test out. You should be able to login then get your xml file. I'm not sure if StackOverflow notifies you when I edit my answer which is why i'm commenting here as well (new guy here).

Comment: Hey,

Thanks for your help. i will try that out. hopefully it will work.

Comment: That's great. Anyway I can get a correct answer if that worked out fine? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Read the documentation for [`XML::Simple`](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aSimple). Notice that the `XMLin` method can take a file handle, a string, and even an `IO::Handle` object. What it can't take is a URL via HTTP.

Use the Perl module [`LWP::Simple`](http://p3rl.org/LWP%3a%3aSimple) to fetch the XML file you need and pass that through to `XMLin`.

You'll have to download and install `LWP::Simple` via using [`cpan`](http://p3rl.org/cpan), as you did before for `XML::Simple`.

Comment: problem?  That's not a problem.  XML::Simple isn't either.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have any specific reason to stick with XML::Simple, then use some other parser like XML::Twig, XML::LibXML which provides an inbuilt feature to parse the XML available through web.

Here is the simple code for the same using XML::Twig

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;
use LWP::Simple;

my $url = 'http://website/computers/computers_main/config.xml';
my $twig= XML::Twig->new();
$twig->parse( LWP::Simple::get( $url ));
```

As said, XML::Simple does not have such in-built feature.

Comment: hey thanks for your reply but 
with using XML::Twig i am getting error saying  "no element found at line 1, column 0, byte -1 at /ur/lib/perl5/site_perl/5/10/i686-cygwin/XML/Parser.pm line 197 at test.pl line 16" any idea what could go wrong ?